# Class, Interface, Generics .... need simplification

Tags: c#, .net, generics

At this time, I have this piece of code for my "employee" class. But I have almost the same for "customer" and all the others.

Is there a way to create an equivalent of my class "EmployeeRepository" but more something like this MyRepo<Employee> but implement IEmployeeRepository in this case, ICustomerRepository if I do this MyRepo<Customer>. Of course the get method return Employee, Customer or other ...

```
public class EmployeeRepository : NHRepository<Employee>, IEmployeeRepository
{
    public Employee Get(Guid EmployeeId)
    {
        return base.Get(EmployeeId);
    }
}

public interface IEmployeeRepository : IRepositoryActionActor<Employee>
{

}

public interface IRepositoryActionActor<T>
{
    T Get(Guid objId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, like Spencer Ruport already mentioned, gather your code in an Interface or abstract base class as I did:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    void DoSomething( );
}

public abstract class Person : IPerson
{

    public virtual void DoSomething( )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public override void DoSomething( )
    {
        base.DoSomething( );
        /* Put additional code here */
    }
}

public class Customer : Person { }

public class PersonRepository<T> : System.Collections.Generic.List<T> where T : IPerson, new( )
{
    public T Get( Guid id )
    {
        IPerson person = new T( );
        return (T)person;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't edit but there is some syntax error in the code, if you can correct. But that's work. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can - except you would make the IEmployeeRepository interface generic as well, so you would have:

```
public class MyRepo<U> : NHRepository<U>, IRepository<U>
{
...

}

public interface IRepository<T> : IRepositoryActionActor<T>
{

}

public interface IRepositoryActionActor<T>
{
    T Get(Guid objId);
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Is it possible in "public interface IRepository<T> : IRepositoryActionActor<T>" to add a method to implement depending of T value ?

Answer (score 1):

> At this time, I have this piece of
>   code for my "employee" class. But I
>   have almost the same for "customer"
>   and all the others.

Figure out what they have in common and give a name to that set of data and create an interface for it. My guess would be IPerson would probably work.

Then you can create a get person repository which returns an IPerson object and can either be an Employee or a Customer.

Comment: IRepositoryActionActor is common for all (Employee, Customer, ....) but IEmployeeRepository (ICustomerRepository, ...) add some specific declaration